# How to define a variable that was in a defined function?

Tags: python

So my defined function includes the variable "name", and whenever I call this function "name" is not defined because it is not defined outside of that function.

Question: I want to know how I can fix this so that the program still knows the variable after having called the defined function.

My code:

```
def getting_name():
    name = input("\n\nWhat is your name? --> ")
    print("\n\nHello " + name + "!")
    return 

# Start of my program

getting_name()

print("You are cool, "+ name)
```

Now I know I can just include the print statement in the defined function, but given from instructions, I can only define the getting name part of the function. Anyways, how do I define "name" so that it actually prints it?

Comment: `return name` ? and then also `name = getting_name()`

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. I typed that in the defined function

Comment: That's how it's done, so you must be missing something. What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks it works now. Wow small details like that stop the entire program. By the way, is adding "name" to return, necessary? Like can I just leave it as return

Comment: There's no way the function would know what it should return if you didn't specify.

Comment: @JohnRow You must specify the variable to return. If you just use `return`, the function return any value

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Also if I were to define another function, which had no variables, only print statements, would I still need to include "return ___" or just return

Comment: You need to stop thinking in terms of variables and start thinking in terms of values.

Comment: @JohnRow It's entirely up to you whether you want the function to return something. If you don't care, then you just need to do `return`.

Answer (score 2):

See comments in code.

```
def getting_name():
    name = input("\n\nWhat is your name? --> ")
    print("\n\nHello " + name + "!")
    return name # you should return name variable

# Start of my program

name = getting_name() # you should assign to new variable return of ur function

print("You are cool, "+ name)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it works now. Also do you know the purpose of adding the variable name to the "return" part. I've done it once just by putting "return" on it's own and it was fine

Comment: Maybe for clarity, to show that they are not the same thing, give `name` in the function and `name` out of the function different names?

Comment: @JohnRow you should read about scopes in docs (https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) for clearly understanding :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your function return the `name`... so in the last line of the function, do `return name`.

When you call `getting_name()`, the function will now return a string that is the name. So you can do something like, `name_received = getting_name()`. Then you can simply `print(name_received)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning the variable value from the function, for it's use outside the scope of the function definition.

Please find the following code snippet for your reference:

```py
def getting_name():
    name = input("\n\nWhat is your name? --> ")
    print("\n\nHello " + name + "!")
    return name

# Start of my program

name = getting_name()

print("You are cool, "+ name)
```

**Please do up-vote, if you find my answer helpful! :)**

Answer (score 0):

Below the working code:

```
def getting_name():
    name = input("\n\nWhat is your name? --> ")
    print("\n\nHello " + name + "!")
    return name

# Start of my program

#getting_name()

print("You are cool, "+ getting_name())
```